# How to skip 'Please remove the installation medium then press enter'

Tags: ubuntu, live-usb, shutdown, lubuntu

I have a time-consuming program running in Lubuntu 18.04 Live. It will take around one day to finish. After the program finishes the computer shuts down.

But since I am running Lubuntu Live, the computer asks me to

> Please remove the installation medium then press enter

after initiating the shutdown.
I will be traveling away before the program can finish and will not be back in a few weeks. I don't want the computer to be powered on all that time.

My question is: Is there a timeout after which the computer will eventually shut down, or is there any way to skip this prompt and completely shut down Lubuntu Live?

Comment: Sorry I missed 'Live' in the os description!

Comment: You can always do poweroff -f, which will shutdown unconditionally and immediately. As this is livecd it should be fine, just be sure to unmount any file system you using.

Comment: @gena2x Yes that works, thank you. I can use that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the computer isn't "up and running" at that point. The OS has been unloaded and it's safe to turn it off. Is using a plug with a timer an option? That way you can set it to just turn off the power after a day or so.

Comment: @terdon well using a timer would mean having to unplug the computer so that is not an option for me, as the program is already running and it is not easy to stop and resume (i am running automated data recovery)

Comment: I got the same error and i used the below command and it was work for me.
First, run this command:
all_generic_ide pci=nommconf
and then this command:
ide=nodma acpi=off

Comment: OP didn't mention any errors. And you should explain what your "command" does.

Comment: @annahri i am talking about this error 'Please remove the installation medium then press enter' while installing Ubuntu might get this error and first run all_generic_ide pci=nommconf and then run ide=nodma acpi=off

Answer (score 2):

In situations, where a remotely accessed rescue system is already running and a reboot into the installed OS is required, the prompt can be disabled by editing the file `/sbin/casper-stop`.

E.g., at the end of `/sbin/casper-stop`:

```bsh
    eject -p -m $device >/dev/null 2>&1

    [ "$prompt" ] || return 0
```

add an unconditional `return 0`:

```bsh
    eject -p -m $device >/dev/null 2>&1

    [ "$prompt" ] || return 0

    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `noprompt` to the kernel command line (e.g., type <kbd>e</kbd> at the grub menu or the suggested <kbd>F*n*</kbd> key).

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/casper.7.html#:~:text=noprompt) for other live boot options.

Comment: +1, this answer is the easiest to implement and can be undone easily (if you add/remove `noprompt` from grub's config)

Answer (score 1):

`/sbin/casper-stop` already has (or has since had added) code to handle this situation if the file `/run/casper-no-prompt` exists.

You can create a simple systemd unit file to always create this:

```
mint@mint:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/casper-no-prompt.service 
# see /sbin/casper-stop
[Unit]
Description=Casper no-prompt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=touch /run/casper-no-prompt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
mint@mint:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
mint@mint:~$ sudo systemctl enable casper-no-prompt
mint@mint:~$ sudo systemctl start casper-no-prompt
mint@mint:~$ sudo systemctl status casper-no-prompt
● casper-no-prompt.service - Casper no-prompt
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/casper-no-prompt.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-11-28 09:19:33 GMT; 1s ago
    Process: 4931 ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch /run/casper-no-prompt (code=exited, status=0/S>
   Main PID: 4931 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 28 09:19:33 mint systemd[1]: Starting Casper no-prompt...
Nov 28 09:19:33 mint systemd[1]: casper-no-prompt.service: Succeeded.
Nov 28 09:19:33 mint systemd[1]: Finished Casper no-prompt.
mint@mint:~$ ls -l /run/casper-no-prompt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 28 09:19 /run/casper-no-prompt
mint@mint:~$
```

Comment: What can u do in Finnix ? This only works in Ubuntu

Comment: On Finnix the behaviour can be changed by setting `LIVE_MEDIUM_EJECT_VERBOSE=false` prior to shutdown.  This can be set in `/etc/tools/live.conf` (see the `/bin/live-medium-eject` script for details of the implentation), although since Finnix is designed to be used in "live" read-only mode, I'm not sure how you would do this persistently.

Comment: I have found the solution yesterday https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645377/force-finnix-linux-rescue-disk-to-shutdown-without-prompting-to-remove-cd-when and about how i did the read only mode, is I modified that live CD using squashfs tool and repack back.

Comment: Is there a documentation about that somewhere? You just gave me valuable info here.

Comment: I don't know, I just read the code.  :-)

Comment: I mean the documentation for Finnix stated the location of the code. I don't think this is documented in their website. I also found the location of `/bin/live-medium-eject` by luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will work on:

- Operating System: Linux Mint 20.3 Live
- Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-91-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

Method: Edit the `casper-stop` file:

```
sudo gedit /sbin/casper-stop +126
```

- The original will look like this:

  ```bsh
   if [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && plymouth --ping; then
          plymouth watch-keystroke > /dev/null
      else
             read x < /dev/console
      fi
  ```
- Change this to:

  ```bsh
   if [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && plymouth --ping; then
          plymouth watch-keystroke > /dev/null
      else
          x='\n'
          #read x < /dev/console
      fi
  ```

Now it doesn't ask for confirmation of the shutdown.

Comment: Can you confirm that this exact solution solves the user's issue, taking into consideration that the user in the question is not using Linux Mint 20.3 Live, but Lubuntu 18.04 Live.